# Developing Flutter iOS Plugins: Specifying Source for Installing Third-Party Libraries in the Podspec File

Tags: flutter

I need to develop a Flutter plugin that requires third-party libraries. The installation method for the third-party library is as follows and requires specifying the source:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/volcengine/volcengine-specs.git'
pod 'Ads-CN', '5.6.1.1'
```

The podspec file for the plugin project's iOS part is as follows:

```
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html.
# Run `pod lib lint duanju.podspec` to validate before publishing.
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'duanju'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter project.
  DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files     = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency       'Flutter'
  s.platform         = :ios, '11.0'

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

How can I add the above third-party library to this file and specify the required source?"